# Python script in cron job stops after some time

Tags: python, linux, cron

I am running a script via cron job and it stops randomly after some time. Here is cron job command.

```
source /home/cpanel-user/virtualenv/mywebsite.com/cgi-bin/3.7/bin/activate && cd /home/cpanel-user/mywebsite.com/cgi-bin && python /home/cpanel-user/mywebsite.com/cgi-bin/faheem.py >> /home/cpanel-user/logs/faheem.py.log
```

Why it is happening?

Below command line is supposed to record logs when the script finishes. But I only see print statements in the log file and no error message.

```
>> /home/cpanel-user/logs/faheem.py.log
```

How do I print the error message or figure out why it is stopping?

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
source /home/cpanel-user/virtualenv/mywebsite.com/cgi-bin/3.7/bin/activate && cd /home/cpanel-user/mywebsite.com/cgi-bin && python /home/cpanel-user/mywebsite.com/cgi-bin/faheem.py >> /home/cpanel-user/logs/faheem.py.log 2>&1
```

Comment: you should explain what is done here and why it solves the question

Comment: In shell, 0 means stdin, 1 means stdout, 2 means stderr. ">>" only get stdout message. so, if you want to get error message, you should redirect stderr(1) to stdout(2).